# Get mouseenter <li> children <div> height

Tags: jquery

I have structure

```
<div id="id">
    <ul>
        <li class="li-1">
            <div style="height: 0px;">
                <div>
                    <div class="col-1">
                        <div class="component"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-2">
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#About2008"><span class="icon-picture">2008</span></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#About2009"><span class="icon-headphones">2009</span></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#About2010"><span class="icon-home">2010</span></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#About2011"><span class="icon-facetime-video">2011</span></a></li>    
                            <li><a href="#About2012"><span class="icon-envelope-alt">2015</span></a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-3"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

```js
$('#id').on('mouseenter', '> ul > li', function() {
    var li = $(this)
})
```

Now I want to alert `.col-2` height. I do:

```
$('#id').on('mouseenter', '> ul > li', function() {
    var li = $(this)
    alert(li.children(".col-2").height());
})
```

But I always get `null`? How can I get the right value?

Comment: I don't see any element with id `id`

Comment: Give us the correct code then. ( a proper example )

Comment: @DmitrijHolkin You're saying `clicked element` but using `mouseenter` event

Comment: I want to know just how to get li element children with class col-2, everything else does not matter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

children with filter gives you refrence of direct children only . use find

```
 $('#id')
    .on('mouseenter','>ul>li',function(){
        var li=$(this);
        alert(li.find( ".col-2" ).height());
    })
```

**LIVE** http://jsfiddle.net/mailmerohit5/pn80krf9/

Comment: glad to help you .. happy coding :)

Answer (score 1):

This is better achieved using the `find` call instead of `children` assuming there is only one `col-2` inside the `li`. Please see working code snippet

```js
$('#id')
  .on('mouseenter', '>ul>li', function() {
    var li = $(this).closest('li')
    alert(li.find(".col-2").height() + "px");
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="id">
  <ul>
    <li class="li-1">
      <div style="height: 45px;">
        <div>
          <div class="col-1">
            <div class="component">
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque a risus id magna aliquet facilisis in ut dolor. Praesent non ipsum pulvinar, interdum urna in, facilisis risus.
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-2">
            Donec sollicitudin nibh vitae tellus dapibus iaculis. Duis nec sem enim. Nullam tincidunt ex a lacinia egestas. Maecenas pulvinar tempor neque at posuere.
          </div>
          <div class="col-3">
            Vestibulum eu imperdiet nulla. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Duis posuere lacus augue, ut aliquet elit fermentum faucibus. Cras commodo dolor sit amet dictum fermentum.
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: li element is itself in refrence of event why `var li = $(this).closest('li')`??